# How to get value from radio button in fbjs

Tags: javascript, fbjs

in my app, i used radio button now the problem is how to get the value from it in fbjs.
I am using 10 radio buttons and have 10 values ie from 1 to 10.I tried using .getValue() but it returns only 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i < document.getElementById('ques_form').getElementById('radio').length; i++)
{
 if (document.getElementById('ques_form').getElementById('radio[i]').getChecked)
 {
  var user_answer = document.getElementById('ques_form').getElementById('radio[i]').getValue;
 }
}
```